# ImageBrush data binding in UWP gives error when ImageSource is null

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

It has been suggested at many places that to have a round image in UWP following code could be used.

```
<Ellipse Width="250" Height="250">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="url" />
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

What I want to achieve is bind the ImageSource to ViewModel like

```
<Ellipse Width="250" Height="250">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind ImageUrl}" />
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

However, whenever the ImageUrl is null I get an exception

```
{System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.

value
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(Type type, Object value)
   at Views.DetailView.DetailView_obj1_Bindings.Update_ImageUrl(String obj, Int32 phase)
   at Views.DetailView.DetailView_obj1_Bindings.Update_(Episode obj, Int32 phase)
   at Views.DetailView.DetailView_obj1_Bindings.ProcessBindings(ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)}    System.ArgumentException
```

Comment: `x:Bind` --- is it a typo?

Comment: No, UWP allows this new syntax of x:Bind along with Binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a type mismatch. The `ImageSource` property is of type `ImageSource` and your `ImageUrl` is probably a `string`. It would work using classic `{Binding }` instead of `{x:Bind }` but with `{x:Bind }` you need to an an converter that converts the `string` to `ImageSource` (by creating a new `BitmapImage` for example).